# Proper syntax for 'curly' brackets after the pipe operator in R

Tags: r, curly-braces, evaluate

Forgive me for asking what might be a simple question, perhaps I am misunderstanding how the curly brackets `{}` work specifically in R, but I am seeing some odd behavior - likely due to my own misunderstandings - and wanted to reach out to the community so I can understand my programming better. I am also not sure why I am seeing the `is.na` call returning an inappropriate result.

I have several columns of data with a number of na's in one or more columns. After removing the rows containing na's in one column, I want to check the data to make sure I know how many rows are left and document that all the na's are removed. I can do this in 3 separate lines, but am trying to use the pipe operator for simplicity.

```
library(magrittr)

df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10, 3, 5),   #create a quick data frame without any na values
                 b=rnorm(10, -3, 5))
df %>% head()        #works
df %>% count()       #works
df %>% sum(is.na())  #doesn't work - error
#Error in is.na() : 0 arguments passed to 'is.na' which requires 1

df %>% sum(is.na(.)) #returns random number (perhaps sum of all values) instead of zero??
```

Perhaps a separate question, but why doesn't the first one work, and why does the second one not evaluate the 'is.na' argument?
If I put curly braces around the 3rd argument, it returns the correct value:

```
df %>% {             #works, but why is this different?
  sum(is.na(.))
}
#[1] 0
```

Now when I try and evaluate all 3, I don't understand the behavior I see:

```
df %>% {             #doesn't work - error
  head()
  count()
  sum(is.na())
}
# Error in checkHT(n, dx <- dim(x)) : 
#   argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

```
df %>% {             #returns appropriate na count of zero, but nothing else is evaluated
  head(.)
  count(.)
  sum(is.na(.))
}
# [1] 0
```

```
df %>% {             #returns first and third result, but not count(.)
  print(head(.))
  count(.)
  sum(is.na(.))
}
#    a           b
# 1  0.3555877  -7.29064483
# 2 -2.6278037   4.30943634
# 3  5.6163705 -10.31436769
# 4 -2.8920773  -4.83949384
# 5  9.0941861  -0.09287319
# 6  2.6118720 -11.86665105

# [1] 0
```

```
df %>% {             #returns all three like I want
  print(head(.))
  print(count(.))
  sum(is.na(.))
}
#    a           b
# 1  0.3555877  -7.29064483
# 2 -2.6278037   4.30943634
# 3  5.6163705 -10.31436769
# 4 -2.8920773  -4.83949384
# 5  9.0941861  -0.09287319
# 6  2.6118720 -11.86665105

#   n
# 1 10

# [1] 0
```

Thanks for any advice in how to interpret this behavior so I can improve my code for next time.

Comment: `df %>% sum(is.na())` is equivalent to `sum(df, is.na())` and here `is.na()` clearly misses an argument.

Comment: in `df %>% { sum(is.na(.)) }`, `df %>% {` acts like `with(`, and assuming you've injected some NA into df$a and df$b, gives you their sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stems from aspects of how braces behave both in magrittr and base R.

First, why does `df %>% sum(is.na(.))` return an unexpectedly large number, while `df %>% {sum(is.na(.))}` works as you expect? By default, `%>%` pass the left-hand side to the first argument on the function on the right-hand side. So `df %>% sum(is.na(.))` is equivalent to `sum(df, is.na(df))`, which should give you an idea of why it yields a large number. However, [per the magrittr docs](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/#re-using-the-placeholder-for-attributes), this "behavior can be overruled by enclosing the right-hand side in braces." When the rhs is enclosed in braces, the lhs is only inserted where you explicitly add the `.` placeholder. So `df %>% {sum(is.na(.))}` is equivalent to `sum(is.na(df))`.

Second, in

```
df %>% {
  print(head(.))
  print(count(.))
  sum(is.na(.))
}
```

why do you have to wrap `head(.)` and `count(.)` in `print()`, but not `sum()`? This is because, [per the R docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Paren.html), expressions wrapped in `{` return "the result of the last expression evaluated." So the result of `sum(is.na(.))` is returned and automatically printed, but the results of the prior expressions aren't returned, so must be explicitly `print()`ed.

Finally, you might be interested in the [nakedpipe](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/nakedpipe) package, which adds more flexibility to using pipes with embraced blocks of functions.

Comment: I get it now - thank you for that straightforward answer. I will check out the nakedpipe package as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The `%>%` pipe passes the left hand side to the right hand side, so think of it like this:

```
head(df)
# is the same as 
df %>% head()
```

However, if you pass multiple things, you may run into a problem:

```
head(df) 
count(df) 

# is not the same as 

df %>% head() %>% count()
```

In the above, R first processes the `head` then counts the values in `head(df)`, so returns a value of 6.

This is why your pipes are not returning what you expect.

In addition, your `df %>% sum(is.na(.))` is returning 0, because it is evaluating everything as `FALSE` (since there are no `NA` values), and when you sum boolean values `FALSE == 0` and `TRUE == 1`

```
is.na(df)
#          a     b
# [1,] FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE
# [7,] FALSE FALSE
# [8,] FALSE FALSE
# [9,] FALSE FALSE
# [10,] FALSE FALSE

# so 
sum(is.na(df))
# [1] 0
```

You may be most efficient if you wrap what you want in a function and store everything in a list:

```
example_function <- function(x){
  list(head(x), count(x), sum(is.na(x)))
}

example_function(df)

# [[1]]
# a          b
# 1  0.1976218  3.1204090
# 2  1.8491126 -1.2009309
# 3 10.7935416 -0.9961427
# 4  3.3525420 -2.4465864
# 5  3.6464387 -5.7792057
# 6 11.5753249  5.9345657
# 
# [[2]]
# n
# 1 10
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 0
```

Comment: well, not all pipes are created equal  `df |> {
sum(is.na(.))
}
Error: function '{' not supported in RHS call of a pipe`, as I imagine, on reflection it wasn't meant to be; whereas, `df %>% {
 sum(is.na(.))
}
[1] 4`, where 4 NA were injected into df.

Comment: Agreed, the OPs main issue seemed to be the use of pipes, not necessarily the curly brackets. I'll edit just to include `%>%` for simplicity

Comment: Thank you for the example - you are correct that this would be more efficient if there were multiple data frames to analyze, I will keep that idea in my pocket for the future.